# cargar ArrayList de otra clase en un Combobox

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, combobox

Buenas tengo esta clase con su ArrayList:

```
public class Alumnos {

    ArrayList<String> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();

    public Alumnos(VentanaAlumnos vAlumnos) {
        this.vAlumnos = vAlumnos;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getlistaAlumnos() {
        return listaAlumnos;
    }

    public void setlistaAlumnos(ArrayList<String> alumnos) {
        this.listaAlumnos = alumnos;
    }
...
```

y en la otra clase tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class VentanaNotas extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form VentanaNotas
     */
    Alumnos alumno;
    public VentanaNotas() {

        initComponents();
        cargarCombo();


    }
    public void cargarCombo(){
        DefaultComboBoxModel mdlCombo= new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cbAlumnos.setModel(mdlCombo);
        mdlCombo.addElement(alumno.getlistaAlumnos());

    }
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es introducir la ArrayList `listaAlumnos` en mi ComboBox "cbAlumnos" alguien sabe como hacerlo?

(La ArrayList se llena en otro JPanel pero eso funciona correctamente)

con este desarrollo a mi me da NullPointerException, muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: No tienes inicializado alumno.

Answer (score 0):

Te paso un ejemplo sencillo de como llenar un ComboBox con un ArrayList

```
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("valor1");
        lst.add("valor2");
        lst.add("valor3");
        lst.add("valor4");

        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(lst.toArray()));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prueba Combo");
        frame.add(combo);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Saludos desde Argentina